# Wi-Fi WPA2-Enterprise automate connection user/password prompt on windows 8.1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, netsh, wpa2

I am trying to automate the connection to a known wi-fi network on our Windows 8.1. I have read everything online about netsh exporting/importing profiles. Problem is after importing the profile for the first time (on a new system or after deleting the profile), the command *netsh wlan connect name=myprofile* will not connect. I have to manually connect, enter in user/pass. Then the command works for any future connects.

When I exported the profile I used key=clear. No key shows up in the XML.

WiFi settings through the GUI:  Wi-Fi status->WIreless network properties-> Security tab: security type=WA2-ENterprise   Encryption Type=AES  (there is no Key field) 'Choose a network authentication method'=Microsoft:Protected EAP (PEAP)

I need to automate the connection for the first time on a new Win8.1 system. Anything from command line, python, powershell scripts etc would work. I tried using AutoIt but it could not detect or send to the u/p prompt in the sidebar.

output of *netsh wlan show profiles name=myprofile key=clear*:

## Profile LabWLAN on interface Wi-Fi:

Applied: All User Profile

### Profile information

```
Version                : 1
Type                   : Wireless LAN
Name                   : LabWLAN
Control options        : 
    Connection mode    : Connect manually
    Network broadcast  : Connect only if this network is broadcasting
    AutoSwitch         : Do not switch to other networks
```

### Connectivity settings

```
Number of SSIDs        : 1
SSID name              : "LabWLAN"
Network type           : Infrastructure
Radio type             : [ Any Radio Type ]
Vendor extension          : Not present
```

### Security settings

```
Authentication         : WPA2-Enterprise
Cipher                 : CCMP
Security key           : Absent
802.1X                 : Enabled
EAP type               : Microsoft: Protected EAP (PEAP)
802.1X auth credential : User credential
Credentials configured : No
Cache user information : Yes
```

### Cost settings

```
Cost                   : Unrestricted
Congested              : No
Approaching Data Limit : No
Over Data Limit        : No
Roaming                : No
Cost Source            : Default
```